# how to pass variables between 2 php pages when the latter called with require()

Tags: php, require, require-once, require-method

I am a PHP newbie, and I have this question:

say I have:

---

### a.php:

```
$a = 'foo' ;
$b = 'baz' ;
require ('b.php') ;
```

---

How do I pass variables $a and $b to b.php ?
How do I use these variables in b.php ?

thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you call require() after setting the variables, and they should be available in b.php.

a.php:

```
$a = 'foo';
$b = 'baz';
require('b.php');
```

b.php:

```
echo 'a: '. $a;
echo 'b: '. $b;
```

Comment: This method does not work. `$a` and `$b` are both undefined in 'b.php'. There is confusion with the require function here. To get the code above working, `$a` and `$b` can remain defined in 'a.php', but then this file needs to be included/required in 'b.php' for the variables to be recognised in the 'b.php' file. Not the other way round, like the above example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these variables straight away in b.php

require(), include(), etc... includes the file in the same scope as the include is made, except for functions/classes that get included in the global scope.

Here's the link to the documentation that explains it nicely : http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php