# How to pass variables between 2 PHP files?

Tags: php, html, dom

I have the following code in a file called one.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['one'] = "ONE";
$_SESSION['two'] = "TWO";
?>

<html>
<body>
<a href="two.php">Click here for 1.</a>
<a href="two.php">Click here for 2.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I click on one of the anchor tag links, it takes me to two.php.

Here I want the output to be,

`One was clicked.` OR `Two was clicked.`

How do I make the above output in two.php using PHP?

Comment: have you tried calling your `session` on `two.php` file?

Comment: use `$_GET` or `$_POST` to pass variables

Comment: `$_SESSION` variables are globals, what means you would be able to retreive the value simply by calling `$_SESSION` and its given key, `$_SESSION['one']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables between php scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678567/how-to-pass-variables-between-php-scripts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to append a paramter to the url

```
<a href="two.php?clicked=1">Click here for 1.</a>
<a href="two.php?clicked=2">Click here for 2.</a>
```

then in PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['clicked'])) {
      $clicked = (int)$_GET['clicked'];
} else {
      $clicked = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

code is here,

```
 <?php

    if($_REQUEST['click'] == 1)
    {
        echo "One was clicked.";
    }
    else if($_REQUEST['click'] == 2)
    {
        echo "Two was clicked.";
    }

?>

<html>
<body>
<a href="two.php?click=1">Click here for 1.</a>
<a href="two.php?click=2">Click here for 2.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables by using [`GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) or [`POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) method.

Here is simple `GET (query string)` method.

**main.php :**

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="two.php?btn=One">Click here for 1.</a>
<a href="two.php?btn=Two">Click here for 2.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**two.php :**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['btn'])) {
    echo $_GET['btn'] . " was clicked";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is asked so many times:-

[How to pass a variable value between 2 php files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875968/how-to-pass-a-variable-value-between-2-php-files)

[How to pass variables between php scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678567/how-to-pass-variables-between-php-scripts)

[Pass variables between two PHP pages without using a form or the URL of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778425/pass-variables-between-two-php-pages-without-using-a-form-or-the-url-of-page)

[passing value between two php files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172969/passing-value-between-two-php-files)

[PHP Pass variable to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

[Passing PHP variables between scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269646/passing-php-variables-between-scripts)

[passing variables between functions and files in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293007/passing-variables-between-functions-and-files-in-php)

[PHP Passing variables between two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228186/php-passing-variables-between-two-files)

[Passing multiple variables to another page in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102489/passing-multiple-variables-to-another-page-in-url)

[Use SESSIONS variables between different php files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683125/use-sessions-variables-between-different-php-files)

[how to pass variables between 2 php pages when the latter called with require()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046369/how-to-pass-variables-between-2-php-pages-when-the-latter-called-with-require)

[Transfer variables between PHP pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240470/transfer-variables-between-php-pages)
[phpbb 3.1 passing variable between 2 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294795/phpbb-3-1-passing-variable-between-2-pages)